# Bootstrap 4 fixed and sticky header

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I need your help please help me.
Can i use position fixed and position sticky in a single page.
I want position fixed for primary header and sticky for secondary header.

Thank you in Advance

Comment: can you share some code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask refer this.

Answer (score 0):

This should work as long as you implement the onscroll function.

you would need to set a property for the second header so it properly sits below the current and then when onscroll is triggered it would toggle the css class you define to make the secondary header sticky to the top.